# DNA staining agent with good absorbance at 532 nm

Tags: biochemistry, fluorescence, dna-rna, dye

I need to stain some double-stranded DNA with an intercalating fluorescent dye. For imaging, I am using a microscope setup equiped with a 532 nm green laser.
What is the staining agent of choice to use with a 532 nm excitation source?
Sytox Orange may [work](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/S11368) but it is a bit pricey.

Comment: Did you try  propidium iodide? It is less fluorescent than Sytox Orange, but cheap.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne It is certainly cheap enough and absorbs at the right wavelength, I will try that

Comment: Check this as well: https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/live-or-dye-594-614-50as/501964599